# getting optional with value even after unwrapping it

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, option-type

I have a JSON object which contains some dictionary and arrays as below

```
let stats = screendata["stats"]! as? NSDictionary
```

now when i try to fetch a dictionary from it it gives me an optional dictionary so how can I remove this optional word ?

```
print(stats!["reward_listing"]! as? NSDictionary)
```

this is output I am getting

```
Optional({
"btn_label" = "905 points to go";
description = "Free any size drink at Starbucks";
id = 1;
price = "1000 Points";
status = disable;
title = "Free any size drink at Starbucks";
})
```

please guide me about how to remove this optional word ?

Comment: `if let stats =  screendata["stats"] as? [String:AnyObject], let reward = stats["reward_listing"] as? [String:AnyObject] { print(reward) } `

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that you have force-unwrapped `screendata["stats"]`, but you then use the `as?` operator to cast to `NSDictionary`. `as?` returns an optional, returning `nil` if the cast fails. You could combine both steps into a single line:

```
let stats = screendata["stats"] as! NSDictionary
```

This will both cast to `NSDictionary` *and* force-unwrap. That being said, you should probably think of `!` as the "please crash now" operator and use the much safer `if let` instead:

```
if let stats = screendata["stats"] as? NSDictionary {
    print(stats)
} else {
    //either `screendata` had no entry for "stats" or it wasn't an `NSDictionary`
    print("Couldn't unwrap.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure, that it will be always NSDictionary, you can use `as!` instead of `as?` 
That could solve the problem. 
But better way will be to unwrap it using if-let statement like this:

```
if let listing = stats!["reward_listing"] as? NSDictionary {
    print(listing) 
} else {
    print("Failed to unwrap")
}
```

Usually you should get rid of exclamation marks, because they often lead to errors in runtime. 
Rewrite your first statement using if-let too.

Comment: "Usually you should get rid of exclamation marks, because they often lead to errors in runtime.". That's the whole point. Find the bugs at the topmost-level instead of having unexpected nil-pointers float around in the code without knowing where the bug appeared.

Answer (score -1):

try this -

```
guard let stats = screendata["stats"] as? NSDictionary 
  else 
  {
   // Value requirements not met, do something
  return
  }

  // Do stuff with stats
```

Comment: Don't test for `nil` and then force-unwrap; that's what `if let` is for.

Answer (score -2):

```
print((stats!["reward_listing"]! as? NSDictionary)!)
```

replace it with this one will remove optional. 
! stands for Required which means there will be some values always.

Comment: This is redundant. Why use `as?` if you're just going to force-unwrap it right afterwards? That's what `as!` is for.

Comment: you are right but  i just  wanted him to answer in the way he could easily understand.